# Assume you have 7-elements sample and you know that its IQR is 2.What is the smallest possible value sample standard deviation?

Tags: probability, statistics

I have no idea how to solve this problem. Basically find the smallest std with only provided IQR.

Comment: Well, what makes a standard deviation large or small?  There's a certain way you would like to arrange the data.  Try examples.  Does 1,1,1,1,1,1,1 fail?  Why?  Does 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 fail?  Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartile), there is no universal agreement on how to calculate this (see the section on methods for discrete distributions).  So you will need to check if your instructor or textbook has chosen a standard.

If we use Method $1$ from the link, the median is the $4$th number out of the $7$, and to find the first quartile, we take the bottom $3$ numbers and find the median of those, in other words, the second number.  Meanwhile the $6$th number is the third quartile.

So: we know the IQR is $2$.  So the sixth number is $2$ more than the second number in the list.  Other things being equal, a symmetrical distribution will have a smaller standard deviation than a skewed one (elements farther from the mean count more).  So for example we could have the second number be $1$, the median be $2$, and the third quartile, the sixth number in the list, $3$.

Where can you put the other values: first, third, fifth, and seventh, to get
them as close to the mean as possible?

Comment: got your idea. The list gonna be 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 in order to get the min std

Comment: @AcatAdog Exactly.